# SSM connection from local to AWS ECS with Port Forwarding

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, devops, amazon-ecs

I have my java application running in AWS ECS container and 8000 as exposed port

My ECS is running under private Subnet

I want to connect to my ECS through the session manager like this:

```
aws ssm start-session --target My-ECS-Instance-ID --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession --parameters '{"portNumber":["8000"], "localPortNumber":["8000"]}' --region My-Region
```

And the connexion seems to be established without any problems:

```
Starting session with SessionId: botocore-session-1******-09cf*********8
Port 8000 opened for sessionId botocore-session-1******-09cf*********8.
```

But unfortunately when i curl this url:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8000/api/user/9"
```

It generates the following output:

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: Did you verify if port 8000 is correctly exposed in EC2 host?

Comment: Yes it's well exposed in my container definition:
 `PortMappings:
     - ContainerPort: 8000`

Comment: Oh you didn't specify the hostport, so it will be mapped to different port in EC2 host. You might need to ssh to the box (via SSM session manager) and run docker ps to get the actual host port. Then update your above command with this value.

Answer (score 12):

For others that come here looking for a way to forward a port to a Task running in Fargate (as opposed to an EC2 node), here is how:

the docs for `aws ssm start-session`'s `--target` parameter says that you need EC2 instance id, BUT it can also take a value in format of `ecs:<cluster-name>_<task-id>_<container-runtime_id>`

Note that the ECS Task Role will need the following permissions for this to work

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": [
            "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
            "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
            "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
            "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
       ],
      "Resource": "*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I was searching for this! But cannot get it working unfortunately. Any tips on how to debug the not-found errors in this case...? "An error occurred (TargetNotConnected) when calling the StartSession operation" Edit: got it working, used wrong params, but still curious how to debug :)

Comment: I rolled this into a handy wrapper: https://github.com/alastairmccormack/ecs-tunnel
It also adds support for connecting to a remote host (like SSH -L) and acting as an HTTP proxy (similar to SSH -D).

Comment: Can somebody link some docs to this?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in your comment, you specified `ContainerPort: 8000` without HostPort. Hence, the actuall port number in EC2 box will be different. More details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions-portmappings.html)

Please use SSM session manager to ssh to the EC2 host, and then run `sudo docker ps` to find out the correct port number. Then, use this value in your `aws ssm start-session` command.

Comment: I checked the actual port number in EC2 box:


`2e86df16889a        My-Java-App   "/bin/sh -c 'java -j…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours              0.0.0.0:32769->8000/tcp   ecs-My-Java-App `

it is mapped with 32769 

I create new SSM session:
`aws ssm start-session --target My-ECS-Instance-ID --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession --parameters '{"portNumber":["32769"], "localPortNumber":["32769"]}' --region My-Region`

Then curl this:
`curl -X GET "http://localhost:32769/api/user/9"`

==> My curl finish with time out

Comment: can you test the connectivity with telnet or similar tool ?